# PHPBB 3.0.10 and avatar from different server

Tags: php, forum, phpbb, phpbb3, avatars

I'm dealing with the avatar problem. Because my forum is joined with another one. I want to specify the common avatar path.

I thought, that when I specify the full path: http://www.example.com/images/avatars/gallery,

and http://www.example.com/images/avatars/upload the problem will be solved. But there is a dialog box saying, that the path is not correct, and couldn't find on THIS server (no the one from my URL). Can any one give me any clue?

Best regards!

Comment: Are you trying to upload a file to a remote server directly??

Comment: - Polish error is saying that: "Cannot find this path "http://www.example.com/images/avatars/gallery" on my server.

1) my forum is on the domain1/server1. next forum is on the domain2/server2 but they are partially sharing same database. I would like to have same, sharing avatar path.

Comment: are the two forums on the same server, or are they completely separate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are attempting to use it is incorrect. `Avatar Storage Path` requires the path be local to **this** instance of PHPBB3. That means it must be a local path.

An alternative, that will require the user to set the avatar on both boards, is to set `Enable Remote Avatars` to Yes. Users can then set the URL to their avatar on both boards. It's slightly more cumbersome, but will still allow you to share 1 avatar across both boards.

Take a look at Section 3.2.1.4 in this document: https://www.phpbb.com/support/documentation/3.0/adminguide/acp_general.php